# Where should I store browser fingerprint?

Tags: database, security, cookies, browser, fingerprint

I am wondering where should I store generated browser fingerprint (I already have a data). In my internal database (for example MySQL)? Is it that easy?

The purpouse is to identify visitor without need to log in.

Comment: Well, if you have data that you want to store, a database seems like a reasonable option.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's easy to store the fingerprint  in the form of BLOB
is a collection of binary data stored as a single entity( like images...... )
You can use use it to store the fingerprint  database

Comment: Are you for real? A "browser fingerprint" isn't binary data, it's a string.

Comment: He's not talking about a fingerprint from a human. You understand that, right?